# SQL Error in Case Statement

Tags: mysql, compiler-errors, type-conversion, case

I need help with the following case statement:

```
Select Distinct Case
Case When convert(int, cd.location) = 'H ' Then ''
     When convert(int, cd.location) = 'U8' Then ''
     When convert(int, cd.location) = 'A ' Then ''
     When convert(int, cd.location) = 'OH'   Then ''
End as LocationCleanup
```

The problem is the 4 values ('H ', 'U8', 'A ', 'OH') are datatype varchar(10) and obviously contain a non-numeric character, therefore, they cannot be converted to int (I think).  Additionally, cd.location datatype is int.  I prefer the column LocationCleanup, to not exist.  The only reason I have it is to attempt to fix the issue for the next case statement that follows the one above.

```
Case when c.formtype = '1500' and cd.location = 21 and ps.specialtycode in ('05','22','1T','1F','30','1C') then '04-Hospitalist'
    when c.formtype = '1500' then '04-Other'
    else '  '
End as DHHClaimtype,
Into ActualTable
From AnotherActualTable
Join a lot of stuff
```

I am receiving the error:  Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'H ' to data type int.  When I drop the table, and rerun the query for troubleshooting, it appears to be random as to which value the error exists on ('H ', 'U8', 'A ', 'OH').  For these 4 values, I would like to them to return blank ('') as these are user entered data errors.

What am I not thinking about?

If it helps, here is the entire query:

```
declare @start date = '06/01/2016';
declare @end date   = '07/31/2017';

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------    ------------------------------------------------
-- Pull all claims with paid date in range parameter
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------    
------------------------------------------------

if object_id('LA_Temp.dbo.Item19') is not null drop table LA_Temp.dbo.Item19
select distinct
c.claimid,  
c.formtype,
c.facilitycode + c.billclasscode as BillType, 
case when primaryclaimid = '' and resubclaimid = '' then 'Clean' else 'Other' end as CleanClaim,
    -- DHHClaimtype 04 needs to be broken out based on provider specialty and location
    Case when c.formtype = '1500' and cd.location = 21 and ps.specialtycode in ('05','22','1T','1F','30','1C') then '04-Hospitalist'
    when c.formtype = '1500' then '04-Other'
    else '  '
end as DHHClaimtype,
c.status,
c.totalpaid, 
e.phystate as MemberState,
e.phycounty as MemberParish,
pc.ParishCode as MemberParishCode,
con.contracted as NetworkProvider,
reject
into LA_Temp.dbo.Item19
from claim c
inner join member m on c.memid = m.memid
inner join entity e on m.entityid = e.entid
left join LA_Temp.dbo.ParishCodes pc on e.phycounty = pc.Parish
inner join contract con on c.contractid = con.contractid
inner join provider p on c.provid = p.provid
inner join provspecialty ps on p.provid = ps.provid and ps.spectype = 
'PRIMARY'
inner join claimdetail cd on c.claimid = cd.claimid and cd.claimline = 1 and 
cd.location not in ('OH', 'A ', 'U8', 'H ') -- just pull the first line to 
grab the location code, exclude any location codes with non-numeric values
where c.paiddate between @start and @end
and c.status in ('PAID','DENIED');

-- add the claim types to the table
EXECUTE LA_Temp.[dbo].[USP_LA_SetDHHClaimType] @Table = 'Item19';
```

Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: I'm a little confused as to what you're really trying to achieve here.  But, perhaps the ISNUMERIC function might be helpful? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnumeric-transact-sql

Comment: I am trying to make the following code run: 



    `Case when c.formtype = '1500' and cd.location = 21 and ps.specialtycode in 
    ('05','22','1T','1F','30','1C') then '04-Hospitalist' 
    when c.formtype = '1500' then '04-Other' else ' ' End as DHHClaimtype, Into 
    ActualTable From AnotherActualTable
    Join a lot of stuff`

Comment: I did finally realize I can "half-way" achieve this by adding cd.location not in ('OH', 'A ', 'U8', 'H ') into the join or where clause. However, I would like to keep the records with these values, while converting the value to blank (' ') at the same time.